# MySQL query for counts by state

Tags: mysql, count, records

Here is my setup

```
database = mine
table = mytable
field = hair
field = eyes
field = state
```

Currently I am able to run a query that gives me the count for anyone that has "brown" in the hair and eyes field. I'm running:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mine.mytable
WHERE hair = 'brown' OR eyes = 'brown'
```

But I need a count for each state that shows brown eyes or brown hair in either field. The only way I know how to do it would be to put an AND state = 'NY' as part of the query, but that would mean I need to run the query 50 times per combination to get a count for each state. How would I go about running a query to give me the count showing each state without running the query 50 times?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) state_count,IFNULL(state,'Total') state
FROM mine.mytable
WHERE hair = 'brown' OR eyes = 'brown'
GROUP BY state WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: With ROLLUP gives you the total last

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by state to get counts by state.

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) count
FROM   mine.mytable.
WHERE hair = 'brown' OR eyes = 'brown'
GROUP BY state
```